# Некорректно сохраняется кириллица в сессии

Tags: php

Сохраняю json-массив с кириллицей внутри в сессии php, а при выводе значения сессии на экран вместо слова `Москва` выводится `\u041c\u043e\u0441\u043a\u0432\u0430`. Что с этим делать и как это расшифровать?

Comment: Во-первых, непонятно, зачем сохранять в сессии json строку. Во-вторых, перед выводом джейсон надо как бы декодировать сначала

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По умолчанию php кодирует кирилицу в Unicode как `\uXXXX`, начиная с php 5.4 есть возможность не кодировать многобайтные символы Unicode, используя предопределенную константу `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`

```
json_encode('Москва', JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)
```

Comment: Как json внутри себя хранит данные - это его личные половые трудности. программиста это не касается. На выходе в любом случае получится корректный текст.

Answer (score 1):

Ничего не делать и никак не расшифровывать. Надо просто использовать штатные средства, а не лезть по пхпшной привычке в специальный формат руками.

если сделать `json_decode('сохраненный текст')` [**то все выведется нормально**](https://3v4l.org/YdJ5b).